# Is this code thread safe? and if not when and how can it go wrong?

Tags: c++, multithreading

OK so I've been told that this code isn't thread safe.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

static int sum[5];

static int get_sum()
{
    int x=0;
    for (int j=0;j<5;++j)
        x += sum[j];
    return x;
}

static void f1(int x){
    sum[x] = 1;
    std::cout << "f" <<x << ": " << sum[x] << " : " << get_sum() << std::endl;
}

int main()  {

    for (int j=0;j<5;++j)
        sum[j] = 0;

    std::thread t0(f1, 0);
    std::thread t1(f1, 1);
    std::thread t2(f1, 2);
    std::thread t3(f1, 3);
    std::thread t4(f1, 4);

    while (get_sum() != 5)  ;

    t0.join();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();

    std::cout << "final: " << get_sum() << std::endl;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the program might fail to complete? I know the running values of get_sum will be non-deterministic and the output from cout will be randomly interleaved but that's not relevant to the program completing.

Comment: Is this a practise exam question or something?

Comment: value of get_sum is undeterministic, based on scheduling..

Comment: Bad form for one thread to read memory (like x += sum[2]) while another thread is writing it (like sum[2] = 1), but it usually works. You are guaranteed trouble when two thread try to change the same memory location.  I think on an x86 the above program would complete,

Comment: @brianbeuning: Incorrect. See my answer. The compiler can move the reads of the array outside the `while` loop.

Comment: Ah.  What if sum[] is volatile?

Comment: @brianbeuning: That makes it much more likely to work, but still not guaranteed. Unfortunately, `volatile` has no guaranteed semantics for multi-threaded code. (Actually, it's fortunate. If it did, that would slow down code that used `volatile` for its intended purposes.) Specifically, `volatile` is not an exception to the rule that concurrent reads and modifications are prohibited by the standard. See my answer for why it's not smart to try to think of all the ways it could fail and fix them.

Comment: I need to check what exactly current standard says about volatile. For now i'm deleting my answer in order not to risk spreading misinformation ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A value may not be accessed in one thread while it might be modified in another. That's the rules.

We can speculate about specific problems that might occur on specific platforms. But generally that's unhelpful because it leads people to think that if they can just fix every possible way they can think of that it might go wrong then their code is okay. But it's not -- things can, and do, go wrong in ways you couldn't have thought of at the time. Please don't start thinking this way. The list of failures caused by this type of reasoning is long and doesn't need to get any longer.

Here's one way it can fail: The compiler might inline `get_sum` and copy all the values into registers before the `while` loop, causing the loop to repeat forever. This is a legal optimization because the compiler can see that your code could read any of those values at any time during the `while` loop, thus no other thread is permitted to modify them during that loop.

Now, if you read this question and the answers, you'll see that a lot of people couldn't think of this way the code can go wrong. But that's okay, they don't have to. These rules exist because it's difficult, perhaps even impossible, to think of all the possible ways code might go wrong. So don't make your code's correctness rely on you having this super-human ability.

Comment: I'd just like any example of where it might fail so I can understand the rationale behind that being the rule.

Comment: You're kind of missing the point. The rule applies even if nobody can think of any possible way it might fail. (But I'll update my answer with one anyway.)

Comment: So, will making sum (the global array) atomic result is the program behaviour being well defined and running to completion?

Comment: I'd have to see the exact changes to be certain, but yes, using atomic types or atomic operations is one way to solve the problem for sure. These operations have precisely-defined, multi-thread semantics.

Comment: I guess the change would be 'static int sum[5];' => 'static std::atmoic<int> sum[5];'

Answer (score 1):

The program is ill-formed because it has undefined behaviour because there is a data race in the access to every single array element, each of which is accessed concurrently by `f1` and `getsum` without any synchronisation.

Comment: @GManNickG: Hurray, finally access to the 'special' section :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is not safe. Because multiple threads are accessing the global sum. get_sum() might read sum[x] uncertain before or after other threads write to relative position.

To be multithreaed safe, shared resource should be protected by lock, such as mutex.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the array sum

Comment: You answer is vague, unhelpful and adds nothing w.r.t. to other existing answers.